# Trigger a Jenkins build when a checkin is made on TFS

Tags: python, jenkins, tfs

Inside a TFS Project, I store some set of python scripts inside a specific folder. So I want to trigger a Jenkins build if a change is made on scripts on the particular folder and not others. Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: It should be CI build, please see [Setting up CI/CD with the TFS Plugin for Jenkins](http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/Setting-up-CICD-with-the-TFS-Plugin-for-Jenkins), hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Jenkins job that checks the modified time (If the scripts are under version control, the commit id) periodically, and if there's a change since the last build, kick off the new build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins service hook in TFS:

1. Go to team project admin page
2. Select Service Hooks
3. Click + to add a new service
4. Select Jenkins> Next
5. Select Code checked in event and specify filter path >Next
6. Specify Jenkins base URL, User name, Password, Build job etc…> Finish

After that, it will trigger a Jenkins build when a checkin is made on specified path.